# SELECT with LEFT JOIN returns NULL values

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I've two tables:

**posts**:

```
id | id_author | content | year
1  | 1         | hello   | 2015
2  | 1         | world   | 2016
3  | 2         | hi      | 2016
```

**favorites**:

```
id | id_author | id_post | year
1  | 3         | 2       | 2016
```

And I want to do a `SELECT` to get the `posts` data by the `favorites` using `LEFT JOIN`. So, I did: (
taking into account that I am logged in with the user with id_author = 3)

```
SELECT p.id, p.id_author, p.content, p.year, f.id_post
FROM favorites f
LEFT JOIN posts p
ON f.id_post = p.id
WHERE f.id_author = 3
ORDER BY f.id
DESC
```

So, I did: (`$sql` is equal to the query above)

```
if(count($sql) > 0) {
    var_dump($sql);
}
```

But the output is:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    NULL
    ["id_author"]=>
    NULL
    ["content"]=>
    NULL
    ["year"]=>
    NULL
    ["id_post"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

Why is returning `NULL`?

Answer (score 2):

Given the schema and data of the OP the following query is not syntactically valid:

```
SELECT p.id, p.id_author, p.content, p.year, f.id_post
FROM favorites f
LEFT JOIN posts p
  ON f.id_post = p.id
WHERE id_author = 3
ORDER BY f.id DESC
```

as there is an ambiguity concerning the field used by the predicate of the `WHERE` clause: `id_author = 3`.

You most probably have `p.id_author = 3`, which means the field of the *right* table of the `LEFT JOIN` operation is used by the `WHERE` clause. This turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` operation, yielding no results. So, you probably have to use:

```
WHERE f.id_author = 3
```

Comment: I'm sorry and I'm edited my question, in fact there is no ambiguity, I just wrote the wrong condition... The query is right now.

Comment: @Igor in this case pls remove the post.